# Como eliminar espaços em excesso em uma string?

Tags: c, string

O código em C para remover os espaços em strings não esta funcionando. Ele para na execução.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void removerSpacos(char str[]) {
int i, j;
int tam = strlen(str);
for(i=0; i<tam; i++) {
        if(str[i] != ' ') {
                str[j] = str[i];
                j++;
    }
}
   str[j] = '\0';

}
int main()
{
   char frase[] = "Ola   Mundo!";
   removerSpacos(frase);
   printf("%s", frase);
   return 0;
}
```

Como deixar a *string* com 1 espaço? Entre as palavras, ali na frase "Ola Mundo" tem 2, e no código ele retira todos os espaços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente o problema é não ter inicializado a variável `j`. Mas a lógica tira todos os espaço, tive que mudar um pouco com o alerta do JJoao nos comentários. Fiz uma otimização, organizei e modernizei o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void removerSpacos(char str[]) {
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 1; str[i]; i++) {
        if (str[i] != ' ' || (str[i - 1] != ' ')) {
           str[j] = str[i];
           j++;
        }
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
}
int main() {
   char frase[] = "Ola Mundo!";
   removerSpacos(frase);
   printf("%s", frase);
   return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/clUQYP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ujkqzipt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Trim.c).

Comment: @JJoao não sei o que aconteceu, eu poderia jurar que estava certo. Já arrumo. Eu quis seguir o algoritmo dele, mas realmente não funciona se a intenção é deixar algum.

Answer (score 1):

Contribuindo para esse tema fiz uma mesclagem de C/C++, objetivando retirar os espaços excedentes, tanto no final quanto no meio de uma string.
Veja o código que consegui

```
string RemoveEspaco(string str)
{
int i, j;
char *input, *out;
string output;

input = new char[str.length()+1];
strcpy(input,str.c_str());

for (i=strlen(input); i > 0; i--)
    {
    if (input[i] != ' ')
        {
        break;
        }
    }
input[i] = '\0';
out = new char[strlen(input)+1];
for (i=0,j=0;i < strlen(input); i++)
    {
    if (i > 1)
        {
        if (input[i] != ' ')
            {
            out[j] = input[i];
            j++;
            }
        else
            {
            if ((input[i] == ' ')&&(input[i-1] != ' '))
                {
                out[j] = input[i];
                j++;
                }
            }
        }
    else
        {
        out[j] = input[i];
        j++;
        }
    }
out[j] = '\0';
output.clear();
output.append(out);

return(output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternativa usando expressão regular do Perl

```
// inclui a Perl Compatible Regular Expression
#include <pcrecpp.h>


char str = "a       b     c";
str = pcrecpp::RE("!\s+!").Replace(" ", &str);
printf(str); // retorna "a b c"
```

**Sobre a library Perl**: http://www.pcre.org/

**O arquivo pcrecpp.h** https://github.com/vmg/pcre/blob/master/pcrecpp.h

Exemplo de como pode implementar no script da pergunta:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcrecpp.h>

void removerSpacos(char str[]) {
    str = pcrecpp::RE("!\s+!").Replace(" ", &str);
}

// aqui o restante dos seus códigos
int main() {
   char frase[] = "Ol.....
```

Comment: @ Daniel, gostei (+1) mas escou com dificuldades de o compilar. Será que podias juntar o mínimo necessário para que a compilação seja possível?

Comment: @JJoao, adicionei exemplo e link para o pcrecpp.h